# Why is it allowed to label almost every statement in Java?

Tags: java

I understand that the main purpose of labels is to use them with `break` and `continue` to alter the usual behaviour of the loop. But it's possible to label every statement that is not a declaration.

```
int j = 0;
LABEL1: j++;
LABEL2: for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
    if (i == 3) break LABEL2;
}
```

Is there any purpose to labels like `LABEL1` since it's not allowed to `break LABEL1`?

Comment: Because, as usual, [that's what the spec says.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7)

Comment: @VladimirHrud Why not? How would you redefine the spec to make it more useful?

Comment: You can still `goto` to them, I think

Comment: @injecteer Java doesn't have `goto`

Comment: @Crozin Are you Sure?

Comment: @Crozin It's a strange one really, the keyword is reserved but it's currently still marked as "unused"

Comment: @PeterRader `goto` does exist but is unused, just like `const`

Comment: I think we can expect the resurrection of `goto` in the future. Remember that thing with functional programming / OOP? The OOP-evangelists were stating that FP is baaaad, but now we see that languages like `Clojure` are gaining momentum. If you think about it, the `continue` or `break` statements have their roots in `goto`

Comment: @BenjaminDale Actually, you can use it in [Jasmin](http://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref-_goto.html).

Comment: @injecteer read the JLS section I linked. It specifically says: _"the Java programming language has no `goto` statement."_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An early unreleased version of java used to have GOTO. In order to jump to any statement with GOTO, you have to be able to label it.

Then at some point James Gosling decided that it wasn't a good feature and ripped it out. This involved grepping through all java code that existed at the time and rewriting any GOTO usage; there were 13 uses. (Source: [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ei-rbULWoA&t=17m25s))

So, like GOTO still being a reserved word, it's a remnant of GOTO support.

Comment: @kocko but if you can `goto` *any* statement in the early version, the spec allowed gotos to be on *any* statement.  Thus, the presence of goto means that labels can't be restricted to just certain statements.  Changing the spec would mean that code written for version n-1 wouldn't compile on n because of a label that was allowed.